# using ngx-toastr with angular 6 and .net core 2 project

Tags: .net, angular6

I am trying to add toast notification in asp.net core 2 with angular 6 project and I follow the documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr/v/8.8.0
but when I run the application I got errors about **ngx-toastr** package, please anybody can help me.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
>
> ERROR in ../node_modules/ngx-toastr/overlay/overlay-ref.d.ts(1,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
>
> ../node_modules/ngx-toastr/overlay/overlay.d.ts(1,58): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
>
> ../node_modules/ngx-toastr/portal/portal.d.ts(1,58): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
>
> ../node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr/toast-injector.d.ts(1,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
>
> ../node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr/toast-noanimation.component.d.ts(1,43): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
>
> ../node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr/toast-noanimation.component.d.ts(2,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser'.
>
> ../node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr/toast-token.d.ts(1,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
>
> ../node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr/toast.component.d.ts(1,35): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
>
> ../node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr/toast.component.d.ts(2,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser'.
>
> ../node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr/toast.directive.d.ts(1,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
>
> ../node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr/toastr-config.d.ts(1,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser'.
>
> ../node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr/toastr.module.d.ts(1,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
>
> ../node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr/toastr.service.d.ts(1,48): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
>
> ../node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr/toastr.service.d.ts(2,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser'.

**package.json** :

```
{
  "name": "Vega",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --extract-css",
    "build": "ng build --extract-css",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build -- --app=ssr --output-hashing=media",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0"
  }
}
```

**angular-cli** :

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.11.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.6.8
@angular/animations          6.0.7
@angular/cli                 6.0.8
@schematics/angular          0.6.8
@schematics/update           0.6.8
rxjs                         6.2.1
typescript                   2.7.2
```

**app.module.ts** :

```
import { VehicleService } from './services/vehicle.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu/nav-menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './counter/counter.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './fetch-data/fetch-data.component';
import { VehicleFormComponent } from './vehicle-form/vehicle-form.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    CounterComponent,
    FetchDataComponent,
    VehicleFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    CommonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'vehicles/new', component: VehicleFormComponent },
      { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
      { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
    ])
  ],
  providers: [
    VehicleService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**vehicle-form.component.ts** :

```
import { VehicleService } from '../services/vehicle.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-vehicle-form',
  templateUrl: './vehicle-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vehicle-form.component.css']
})
export class VehicleFormComponent implements OnInit {
  makes: any[];
  models: any[];
  features: any[];
  vehicle: any = {
    features: [], //we should initialize the features array because we use push() method in onFeatureToggle()
    contact: {}
  };


  constructor(
    private vehicleService: VehicleService,
    private toastr:ToastrService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.vehicleService.getMakes().subscribe(makes =>
      this.makes = makes);

    this.vehicleService.getFeatures().subscribe(features =>
      this.features = features);
  }

  onMakeChange() {
    var selectedMake = this.makes.find(m => m.id == this.vehicle.makeId);

    this.models = selectedMake ? selectedMake.models : [];

    delete this.vehicle.modelId;
  }

  onFeatureToggle(featureId, $event) {
    if ($event.target.checked)
      this.vehicle.features.push(featureId);
    else {
      var index = this.vehicle.features.indexOf(featureId);
      this.vehicle.features.splice(index, 1); // remove one object from the index
    }
  }

  submit() {
    this.vehicleService.create(this.vehicle)
      .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
  }

  onSuccess(){
    this.toastr.success('Hello world','Toastr Fun !');
  }
}
```

Comment: Please make sure that the required modules are installed. The error message clarly says that the modules are not available to Angular compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message is generated when importing a module that is not installed.
Did you run `npm install` in the folder where the `package.json` is before trying to build the application?